# How to get azure storage encryption status

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am trying to get Azure Storage's encryption status from command line or programatically but could not find any relevant cmdlet(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestorageserviceproperty?view=azurermps-6.13.0).
I can check that manually from portal like this

[image]

is it avilable to check through any command line or we have to check only through portal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the command below, make sure you have installed the [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.8.0) module.

```
(Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -ResourceType Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts -Name <storageaccount-name>).Properties.encryption | ConvertTo-Json
```

If the `Encryption type` is `Microsoft-managed keys`, the `keySource` will be `Microsoft.Storage`.

[image]

If the `Encryption type` is `Customer-managed keys`, the `keySource` will be `Microsoft.Keyvault`, `keyvaultproperties` will include the properties of the keyvault key you configured.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`Get-AzStorageAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/Get-azStorageAccount?view=azps-4.3.0) PowerShell Cmdlet.

```
$props = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "your-resource-group-name" -Name "storageaccount-name"
$keySource = $props.Encryption.KeySource
```

`$keySource` should tell you the encryption type used. In my case, it printed `Microsoft.Storage`